# How to enable email Autocomplete in Material UI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following Material UI TextField to capture emails. However, when the user starts typing, emails on the browser are not been suggested as I thought. How can I ensure, email addresses on the browser are suggested as the user types in his/her email.

```
<OutlinedInput
                type="email"
                disabled={authStarted}
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="name@example.com"
                autoComplete={"on"} //This part isn't working
                className={classes.emailField}
            />
```

Comment: what you mean by "emails on the browser" ? . so when the user types "abc@" you want to show the email providers like ( gmail.com, yahoo.com ) as options ?

Comment: I want something similar to this example. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_email_autocomplete The moment you click on the textfield notice the email address on your browser comes up under auto complete

Comment: the difference between input of the example you want and the material-ui OutlinedInput is the `name` property. it's weird to me but when I put `name="email"` property to  OutlinedInput I saw my emails and also my browser is chrome. I hope it helped. https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-nobel-ijfrx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SoroushSalehi404 Oh I see. Thanks for your recommendation. When I added the ```name=email``` property it worked. Really weird. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

simply include the name=email attribute in your input field.

```
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="What is your email?" />
```